# Deploy Spring boot+Angular2 app to Heroku

Tags: spring, angular, heroku

I was trying to deploy my first web-app ( back end - Spring, front end - Angular2 ) to Heroku, but the front end doesn't work properly. This is what I see in logs.

```
2016-11-08T16:53:10.634253+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/login.html" host=organazi.herokuapp.com request_id=86ff1936-97be-4cd1-abea-6553163c834f fwd="91.196.192.37" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=209ms status=200 bytes=1772
2016-11-08T16:53:11.003293+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js" host=organazi.herokuapp.com request_id=8ae3afe7-5721-41ef-9d80-d853ede55e07 fwd="91.196.192.37" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=231ms status=404 bytes=548
2016-11-08T16:53:11.110401+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/systemjs.config.js" host=organazi.herokuapp.com request_id=ee743412-a577-4b4e-b5a0-1a6ed9cd5391 fwd="91.196.192.37" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=88ms status=200 bytes=2077
2016-11-08T16:53:11.096089+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js" host=organazi.herokuapp.com request_id=4954cbe7-832a-4e86-a37f-beb82fc3d567 fwd="91.196.192.37" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=70ms status=404 bytes=549
2016-11-08T16:53:11.116841+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js" host=organazi.herokuapp.com request_id=facea6c9-0c5c-4b68-8b7d-88347054bbd6 fwd="91.196.192.37" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=100ms status=404 bytes=542
2016-11-08T16:53:11.113024+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js" host=organazi.herokuapp.com request_id=5605b488-0a21-49d8-8d71-ef3fd06288e4 fwd="91.196.192.37" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=93ms status=404 bytes=549
2016-11-08T16:53:11.271432+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js" host=organazi.herokuapp.com request_id=c4c5d13d-3311-4d8e-a46a-c14c59b03899 fwd="91.196.192.37" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=27ms status=404 bytes=549
2016-11-08T16:53:11.430986+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js" host=organazi.herokuapp.com request_id=d8f8a2ba-5e10-4d55-8cd1-0c6b5388de26 fwd="91.196.192.37" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=38ms status=404 bytes=549
2016-11-08T16:53:11.613146+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/systemjs.config.js" host=organazi.herokuapp.com request_id=1440d389-ecc9-4537-bcd2-19cc6146e453 fwd="91.196.192.37" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=21ms status=200 bytes=2077
2016-11-08T16:53:11.778848+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/login/blue-sky-hd-wallpaper-2.jpg" host=organazi.herokuapp.com request_id=cd6a19c8-dbd0-4b68-926a-4c760bc9c3a9 fwd="91.196.192.37" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=52476
```

Files like *systemjs.config.js* and image */login/blue-sky-hd-wallpaper-2.jpg* loads fine, but there are some problems with loading *node_modules*. Sitting for 2 weeks with this problem.

My project - https://github.com/BarexaS/Constructed.git

Answer (score 0):

In my Spring Boot and Angular2 setup I have similar issues. Unfortunately I have no solution yet. If you did not add the (generated) node_modules to your VCS (which you should not do anyway) heroku won't be able to detect automatically that your project also contains Node.js dependencies, even if your package.json is checked in. Consequently node_modules won't be available. There is the possiblity to tell heroku that your project is also Node.js based (by specifying it in the Procfile) but in the description heroku will expect that the package.json file is located in the root folder of the Spring Boot app. In my setup it is located in resources/static/js/ so I do not really know how to tell heroku that it first must install the dependencies by calling npm install in this folder.